# JQuery Datepicker - only select mondays and thursdays

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code which only allows users to select Mondays from jquery datepicker.

I want to adapt this to be able to select mondays and thursdays.

Any ideas?

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 1,""]}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add an or (`||`) in there, like this:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
  var day = date.getDay(); 
  return [day == 1 || day == 4,""];
}
```

This only incurs the cost of [`.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) once per date shown, not that it's an expensive operation anyway, but no reason not to be efficient.

Answer (score 3):

**try this**

```
beforeShowDay: function(date)
{ return [(date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 4), ""]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can add this: (disable after days and show Weekdays selected )

For example if you only want monday and friday remember ,0 sunday, 1 monday...... take out the weekdays you want block.

Works 100% on newest Jquery version

```
jQuery(function($){
$("#datepicker_es").datepicker({ minDate: 0,beforeShowDay: function(date)
{ return [(date.getDay() == 2 || date.getDay() == 3 || date.getDay() == 4 || date.getDay() == 5 || date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0), ""]; }});
```

it works for me..... and I hope works for all

Answer (score 0):

```
      beforeShowDay:function(date){ 
               var day = date.getDay(); 
               return [(day == 1 || day == 4),""];
      }
```

Aakash Contractor
    (Asp.net Developer),
   Jain Jamatkhana pase,
   Ahmedabad

Comment: beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
  var day = date.getDay(); 
  return [(day == 1 || day == 4),""];
}