# is there anyway to have a jquery UI date picker only allow saturdays?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a jquery ui datepicker.  I want to add some validation so it only allows people to choose Saturdays instead of any date.

I could validate after the fact but thought it would be slicker to have the datepicker do the upfront validation by only enabling Saturday dates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$("#test").datepicker(
    {
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
          if(date.getDay() == 6){
                return [true];
            } else {
                return [false];
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: very nice.Helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {

    /* your other function code here */

    if (date.getDay() == 6) {
        return [true, ''];
    } else {
        return [false, ''];
    }
}
```

Similar questions:

- [JQuery Datepicker - only select mondays and thursdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805486/jquery-datepicker-only-select-mondays-and-thursdays)
- [jQuery UI Datepicker - allow only certain weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484479/jquery-ui-datepicker-allow-only-certain-weekdays)