# Saturdays only in .JS Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm working with a pre-integrated .js datepicker and need to ensure only Saturdays are selectable.

My code in it's current form:

```
(function($){
    "use strict";

$.fn.gdlr_datepicker_range = function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
        numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {



            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#gdlr-check-in").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#gdlr-check-out").val());
                        return [date.getDay() === 6, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];


        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#gdlr-check-in").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', $("#gdlr-check-out").val());
            if (!date1 || date2) {
                $("#gdlr-check-in").val(dateText);
                $("#gdlr-check-out").val("");
            } else {
                $("#gdlr-check-out").val(dateText).trigger('change');
            }
        },
        closeText: objectL10n.closeText,
        currentText: objectL10n.currentText,
        monthNames: objectL10n.monthNames,
        monthNamesShort: objectL10n.monthNamesShort,
        dayNames: objectL10n.dayNames,
        dayNamesShort: objectL10n.dayNamesShort,
        dayNamesMin: objectL10n.dayNamesMin,
        firstDay: objectL10n.firstDay
    });
```

If somebody could point me in the right direction with a snippet, I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Try from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604435/is-there-anyway-to-have-a-jquery-ui-date-picker-only-allow-saturdays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) on `beforeShowDay` param:

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
> ```
> [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date`s cell or "" for the default presentation
> [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
> ```

It's easy to guess the solution: just change `beforeShowDay` function so that it checks the day of week of selected date when setting the first element of the returned array:

```
return [date.getDay() === 6, /* the rest remains the same */];
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLqxznaq/).

Comment: Thanks for this. Whilst logic dictates this should work, it sadly doesn't.

Comment: Erm. Can you explain how exactly it doesn't work? Have you checked the demo?

Comment: I have checked demo. I'll paste full code example as answer... Thanks!

Comment: Additionally if you'd like to take a look at the front-end datepicker to see the outcome of the above addition, you can find it here http://escocia.frost.digital/reservas/

Like I said, not sure why the getDay() doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: I checked your code, `beforeShowDay` function doesn't even get called (it's easy to check - just set up a breakpoint in the middle of it). That happens because the corresponding datepicker is applied to an empty jQuery object (because `main.init()` is called before DOM is loaded apparently). Now, for some mystic reason these elements are decorated with another datepicker - and that's the one you see. The question is, why so complicated?

Comment: Wow. That's ridiculous. I should add this code in particular was not written by me. We're using an existing theme on this build to speed things up, and this is one of the original parts that hasn't been changed.

Comment: I see. Well, the path is clear - just remove the redundant datepickers, then make sure the one you need are called. I'd bet they'll have their `beforeShowDay` working just fine. )

Comment: Finally figured this out. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction - wouldn't have figured this out without your help!

Comment: Hi raina, sorry to come back to haunt you regarding this matter! Could you show me how to enable only april, may, june, july, august, september by adding to the snippet above? I've been messing around with this all day to no avail!

Comment: Everything I seem to add to this just breaks the calendar! :(

Comment: `date.getMonth() > 2 && date.getMonth() < 9`, check [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eencj6es/) (you'll have to scroll up to 2016 for obvious reasons).

Comment: This works perfect for the month part man - but unfortunately it breaks the Saturdays only part! Really appreciate your time on this one.

Comment: Append `&& date.getDay() === 6` to.

Comment: This project has taught me that I definitely need to take a JS course. I can't seem to append without breaking code. Could I trouble you for once last demo? What does a beer cost where you are raina? Feels like I owe you one.

Comment: Yes, you should take JS course, because it's really [a basic stuff](http://jsfiddle.net/zpcthma8/). )

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the getDay()?

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        if(date.getDay() == 6) {
            return [true];   
        } else {
            return [false];   
        }
    }
  });
});
```